# how to animate background-size only horizontally?

Tags: jquery

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/86cyx/1/)

```
body{
    background: url(path) no-repeat, url(path) no-repeat 50% 0%;
}
```

I wanted to animate the background-size from multiple background image set. But I don't know how to target the background-size of only one image from multiple images. For eg. in my demo I wanted to change the background-size of the second image when the button is clicked. Also the background-size should be changed only horizontally.

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    $('body').animate({
        'background-size': '20%' // '20% 100%' won't work // '100% 20%' won't work.
    },5000); 
});
```

Comment: It's working with css method but not animate method why? http://jsfiddle.net/86cyx/5/

Comment: Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for the click event on the button:

At the end of your html page, add this:

```
<script src="path-to-your-jquery-file"></script>
```

Then, add this:

```
<script>
    $('#your-button').click(function(){
        // Here you must change the css properties of your background
    });
</script>
```

Now, to change only the background's size you must indicate all the sizes. For example, if you have 2 backgrounds you can probably have something like this:

```
background-size: cover, contain;
```

The solution could be:

```
<script>
    $('#your-button').click(function(){
        $('body').css('background-size', '100% 100%, 100% 0%');
    });
</script>
```

If you want to animate, using CSS transitions:

```
body {
    transition: 0.5s background ease;
}
```

CSS transitions: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: You have problems with the "animate" method, this does work: $('button').on('click',function(){
    $('body').css('background-size', '10% 10%, 100% 10%'); 
});

Comment: yeah! it's working with css method but not with animate method http://jsfiddle.net/86cyx/5/

Comment: From the jQuery API site: "All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality" - http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: So, how can I do to achieve my result?

Comment: That's why I've said : 'background-size': '20%' // '20% 100%' won't work // '100% 20%' won't work.

Comment: How about specifying the background-size separated from the background property? see this: http://jsfiddle.net/86cyx/6/

Comment: You did this with css3 transition. that's also good but I'm looking for jquery solution. If not I'll accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: I don´t know a non-css solution for your situation. How about this plugin https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill? is that what you're looking for?

Comment: anyway +1 for your answer.

Comment: Then I can't find another solution, you are looking for something that jQuery by itself does not provide.

Comment: Have you found the answer? It would be helpful for others.